# Can I run dialog, then have the terminal restored to its previous state?

Tags: bash, terminal, dialog, ncurses

I'm reading this document:

[How to use ncurses widgets in shell scripts on Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-ncurses-widgets-in-shell-scripts-on-linux#h3-common-dialog-options)

to learn about using the `dialog` program. The instructions are clear enough and I'm getting some output in a shell variable (when I use `--stdout`). However - when `dialog` exits, it leaves my terminal window "dirty" with the remains of its work:

[image: al]

Can't I make `dialog` restore the contents of the terminal window to its previous state, before it ran? And if I can't - will I have to go back to `echo`'s and `read -p`'s?

Comment: This suggestion could be useful - https://askubuntu.com/a/684192

Comment: @Inian: Thanks, that's just what I need. What a silly option name! I remember I read it as "keep title".